# usemin wont write my files to the output directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

For whatever reason I cannot get usemin to write the output 
below is grunt file code. Its very straightforward

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');


grunt.initConfig(
    {
        useminPrepare: {
            html: 'app/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '/dist',
                root: 'app'
            }
        }
    }
);

grunt.registerTask('build', ['useminPrepare']);
```

};

It seems simple enough and my directory structure is as follows

```
|
+- app
|   +- index.html
|   +- assets
|       +- js
|          +- foo.js
|          +- bar.js
+- dist
```

when I run `> grunt useminPrepare` I get the configuration output
Am I supposed to do something with the configuration out? Am I supposed to copy it anywhere.
I expect that  the dist folder would be created by running the task but it is not

I would expect this

```
|
+- app
|   +- index.html
|   +- assets
|       +- js
|          +- foo.js
|          +- bar.js
+- dist   ///this should be created but it isn't and i have no idea why???
```

My HTML is the following

```
<html>
<body>

 <!-- build:js assets/js/optimized.js -->
 <script src="assets/js/foo.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bar.js"></script>
 <!-- endbuild -->

 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I have looked everywhere for this I literally spent most of today trying to find a good example. I am pretty certain I am doing something wrong. I just don't know what it might be and the documentation is very poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honest to god I looked everywhere and finally saw the same quesition on github.
The answer is that you need to specify the tasks they dont get called by `useminPrepare`
in other words I need to make my task like this

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [ 'useminPrepare', 'concat', 'uglify']);
```

instead of

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [ 'useminPrepare']);
```

The answer was incredibly frustrating because it is nowhere in the documentation.

Comment: It's all there in the readme. See the tasks section: "Usually, useminPrepare is launched first, then the steps of the transformation flow (for example, concat, uglify, and cssmin), and then, in the end usemin is launched."

Comment: I think it needs to be worded better. I read that part and just assumed. I guess that's what happens when you assume. Thank you for pointing that out though.